# How can I read unix pipe in python without blocking?

Tags: python, pipe

I'd like to read the output of a process via a pipe like this:

```
./backup.sh | my-python_program.py
```

My python program currently reads from stdin:

```
buff =  sys.stdin.read()
```

Though this seems naive and seems to block on a script that takes a long time to execute. Is there a better way?

Comment: isn't blocking what you whould expect doing such a call?

Answer (score 1):

not sure how python wraps it but you will want to use [select()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) with a small timeout value.

Answer (score 0):

Pipes are set up explicitly to block and for most purposes it makes sense -- does your program have other stuff that it could be doing when not reading the input?

If so, then you can look into asynchronous I/O, and if you're going to be doing this in python, I'd recommend using [`gevent`[(http://www.gevent.org/) which will let you use lightweight threads that do efficient asynchronous I/O:

```
import gevent
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()

def read_from_stdin():
    buff = sys.stdin.read()
    # Whatever you're going to do with it

def some_other_stuff_to_do():
    # ...
    pass

gevent.Greenlet(read_from_stdin).run()
gevent.Greenlet(some_other_stuff_to_do).run()
```

Comment: Of course, you can use `select(2)`, but it's pretty low-level and `gevent` abstracts away a lot of repetitive details. It can also make use of more efficient algorithms (`epoll(2)` and `kqueue(2)`).